# Return type of main( ) under GNU g++ Compiler

Tags: c++, g++

As per ISO_14882_2014

> 3.6 Start and termination [basic.start]
>
> 3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]
>
> 2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function.
> This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a declared
> return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

*but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.* That means compiler may have its own return type for `main()`. Can you point me to the location where GNU G++ compiler says about `main()`'s return type.

Comment: how about the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) ?

Comment: The "otherwise" applies to the parameter types IIUC

Comment: In what you found it states *It shall have a declared 
return type of type int*.  That is a full stop.  `main` always has to return an `int` because of that sentence.  It's the parameters that are implementation defined.

Comment: I see. the comma (,) after `return type of type int,` is misleading.

Comment: @UjjwalKumar Not really. "but otherwise" means "except for this", not "alternatively".

Comment: @UjjwalKumar - the comma is not misleading.   You are misinterpreting its meaning.     The meaning of the sentence is as Max Langhof described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type must be `int`; the "its type" that follows refers to `main`, not to the return type. That is, the arguments that `main` takes are implementation defined. Each implementation must, however, provide at least `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The comma before the implementation-defined line is misleading

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i386 architecture. From [glibc start.S](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/i386/start.S#L125) we call `__libc_start_main`. From [glibc csu/libc-start.c __libc_start_main](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/csu/libc-start.c) we call `main` with the pointer type `int (*main) (int, char **, char **)` (the `MAIN_AUXVEC_DECL` shouldn't be defined on i386 I think, only for powerpc). So the implementation defined type of `main` function is  `int main(int, char **, char **)`. Because of how stack works on i386, the forms `int main(void)` and `int main()` and `int main(int)` and `int main(int, char**)` will work. The `main` return type is `int`.